# componentDidCatch vs try-catch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

what is the differences, props and cons of this approach:

```
import { createElement } from 'react';

try {

createElement(Greeting, { name: 'Taylor' })

} catch (e) {

console.log(e)

}
```

and Error boundary with componentDidCatch ?